# fetch data as eager with jpa

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I initialize a new spring boot project by version 3.1.0. I have two models like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sub_users")
data class SubUser(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = null,

    @OneToMany(
        cascade = [CascadeType.ALL],
        orphanRemoval = true,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        mappedBy = "subUser"
    )
    val modules: Set<Module>,
)
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "modules")
data class Module(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = null,

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sub_user_id")
    val subUser: SubUser,

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    val moduleType: ModuleType
)
```

Then initialize models with `flyway`:

```
CREATE TABLE sub_users
(
    id          BIGSERIAL    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);


CREATE TABLE modules
(
    id          BIGSERIAL     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    sub_user_id BIGINT        NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT fk_module_sub_user_id REFERENCES sub_users,
    module_type VARCHAR(30),
    UNIQUE (sub_user_id, module_type)
);
```

Repository:

```
interface SubUserRepo : JpaRepository<SubUser, Long>
```

I use `findByIdOrNull()` function of repository.

I add below dependencies to pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I expect that when I use `FetchType.EAGER`, when I call subUsers, the list of modules will also be called and fetched; But this does not happen. I am sure of the existence of the values in the database.

Comment: share your repository class

Comment: repository added. I use `findByIdOrNull()` function.@RobbiNespu

Comment: what is the response you are getting?

Comment: I get subUser with empty list of modules. @404NotFound